# Images load on my index.html but not on my about-us page

Tags: html

`<img src="/images/CFT-Logo cropped.png" alt="Customer First Logo Cropped" class="cft-logo-cropped img-fluid">`

I use the exact same code in both my index.html and about-us.html page.
The image displays on my index page, but not my about-us page.
I have not been able to work out why.

Folder layout below.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: add a full path to your image in `src` in about-us.html page

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by full path?

Comment: `src="http://yoursite.com/images/CFT-Logo cropped.png"`

Comment: Thank you Dean. This works, although I would have preferred to use a relative file path.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your server? Are you even running a dev server or accessing via file protocol?

The path for your source can be written in different ways:

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">
```

The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder in the current folder

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg">
```

The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder at the root of the current web

Answer (score 0):

Try it just referencing directly to the images folder:

```
src="images/CFT-Logo cropped.png"
```

Comment: <img src="images/CFT-Logo cropped.png" alt="Customer First Logo Cropped">
Unfortunately still resulted in just the alt text being displayed.